# UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Tags: java, tomcat

When I am deploying an app in apache-tomcat-5.0.28 I am getting this error:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/opt/devel/server/apache-tomcat-5.0.28/webapps/appServices/WEB-INF/classes/com/xxx/appServices/services/rest/XResource.class]; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:237)
```

Reading similar posts I found that is a problem with the source java version and the compiler version, but when I execute this commands, seems like nothing is wrong...

```
apache-tomcat-5.0.28# java -version
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode)

apache-tomcat-5.0.28# javac -version
javac 1.5.0_22

#javap -verbose XResource | grep version
minor version: 0
major version: 49

#file XResource.class
XsResource.class: compiled Java class data, version 49.0 (Java 1.5)
```

In my pom.xml I have:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
            <configuration>
                ...   
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                <complianceLevel>1.5</complianceLevel>
            </configuration>
```

Any idea of what's going wrong? 
Is possible that the error isn't related to XResource.class?

Comment: Does your class `com.xxx.appServices.services.rest.XResource` implements the `Serializable` interface ?

Comment: No, but uses jersey annotations: 
@Path("/xxx")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class XResource {

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean up your server and re-deploy your application on your server.